# problemas con get y set en python

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gente alguien me puede explicar que pasa?? Porque no se y soy nuevo es un curso de youtube, ese lo que hizo con ese metodo de get y set. Gracias

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y coloca el código como texto. También aclara que parte es la que no entiendes.

Comment: Tienes mal la indentación. Has metido todos los métodos get/set dentro del método `__init__()`, por lo que no son accesibles

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Breve Explicación

En python la función **init**() sirve para inicializar clases. Dentro de esa función se podrán pasar los argumentos a una propiedad propia.

```py
    class miClase():
        def __init__(self, valor1, valor2, valor3):
            self.valor1 = valor1
            self.valor2 = valor2
            self.valor3 = valor3
```

Python es muy exigente con las indentaciones (cuando le das al tabulador estas generando una indentación). Entonces, has definido tus funciones dentro de la función de init. La solución es muy sencilla, borrar y ajustar las indentaciones (cosa que he hecho por ti y ahora te pasaré el código).

## Código

```py
class Cuenta():
    def __init__(self, pro, sal, mon):
        self._propietario = pro
        self._saldo = sal
        self._moneda = mon
        
    def get_Saldo(self):
      return self._saldo
    
    def get_Propietario(self):
      return self._propletario
    
    def get_Moneda(self):
      return self._moneda

    #Metodo Set

    def set_Moneda(self, moneda):
      self._moneda = moneda

cuenta1 = Cuenta("scar Garcia", 15888, "Soles")
print(cuenta1.get_Saldo())
print(cuenta1.get_Moneda())
cuenta1.set_Moneda("Dolares")
```

Comment: la verdad me quedo otra duda mas, porque lo hiciste con un solo guion bajo y funcion?? Se puede hacer tanto con uno como con dos guiones?? y otra cosa, tendiras alguna recomendacion de libros o paginas para aprender python?? soy muy fanatico de este lenguaje, gracias. Tendre en cuenta tu pedido de ser especifico, gracias

Comment: La función de __init__ si o si debe llevar 2 guiones. Respecto a algún libro o similar la verdad es que no. Aprendo mediante la documentación del lenguaje o framework en cuestión.

Comment: gracias. Me refieron a las variables que van con "self._saldo", ahi ppusiste un guion bajo, a eso iba mi pregunta de usa un o dos guiones para las variables

Comment: Las variables no tienen por que usar guion, les puse guion por que vi que en tu código les pusiste. Lo del guión es por una práctica relativamente antigua. Es realmente irrelevante poner o no guión en las variables, queda a tu decisión.

Comment: osea que para el self basta con poner el punto y colocar el nombre de la variable?? el guion bajo pense que era para el uso del self (OBLIGATORIO SI NO NO FUNCIONA), segun el tutorial, Se que para encapsular una variable o funcion se le coloca dos guiones bajo delante es asi o me pasan mal la data??

Comment: La [encapsulación](https://docs.hektorprofe.net/python/programacion-orientada-a-objetos/encapsulacion/) proviene de otros lenguajes, en python se puede lograr si en una clase pones dos guiones después del punto del self y también en una funcion dentro de la clase.

Comment: te agradezco mucho tu tiempo y conocimiento, gracias

Comment: No es nada, siempre es un placer ayudar.

Comment: Para respuestas a próximas preguntas, ten en cuenta que las preguntas que contienen errores tipográficos terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions).